# How to play a mp3 url using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to play a mp3.url using Swift.

Is there any way to use http url in the iOS app? or any other way to do this?

Please I would like to play a mp3.url using Swift.

```
func initPlay(){

     let url = "http://61.80.90.148/mp3-1.mp3"
            audioFile = NSURL(string: url) as URL?
    //error
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFile) 
            } catch let error as NSError { 
                print("error: \(error)")  
            }
    }
```

> ```
> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
> 2019-09-09 10:27:40.046265+0900 Aircon[27673:3377166] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
> ```

Comment: I get a 404 when I hit that URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use direct url to playing music, convert to Data using Alamofire.

```
    Alamofire.download(URL.init(string: "http://61.80.90.148/mp3-1.mp3")!).responseData { (response) in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            do {
                self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(data: value)
            }catch {
                // Error Handling
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2019-09-09 13:28:58.113134+0900 Aircon[30106:3518274] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I only use forced optional in URL and error message means URL is invalid. is it valid url? I cannot access http://61.80.90.148/mp3-1.mp3 and please check it.